Build/Install a Roof Hatch
I own/live in a 1929 shingle roof (~15 years old) home with a 6/12 pitch in eastern Virginia. Access by ladder is cumbersome if not dangerous. I'd like to make an opening in the roof, then build/install a simple hatch in order to gain access through the attic. I'm a very fit (and frugal...) single guy in my 30's, so a plan with the fewest bells & whistles--while still being very sound and watertight--is what I have in mind.
I was surprised to find a dearth of easily accessible information online regarding a project like this. This video seems a perfect match, but I'm casting as wide a net as possible before I make any moves, of course. I'm a fairly experienced house DIYer, but have little experience with roofs. Are there any red flags in this video? Is there a precise guide I can follow that I've missed? Any bits of wisdom are greatly appreciated!

Any hole in a roof is a possible leak location.  ~15 year old roof, I might wait till re-roofing and seal it once.  Doing re-roofing you can also cut it from inside, instead of on top of the roof, making sure you miss cutting the rafters/trusses by mistake.

For the same reason, I would use something like a commercial skylight rather than trying to build something myself.

Thanks to you both - looks like the skylight and kit might be the way to go!

Why do you want to access the roof?

The acute reason is a clogged gutter, but generally I love getting to know all parts of a house; makes me feel "bonded", wacky as that sounds. I also want to check the condition of the shingles and simply enjoy the view periodically.
